# Binary variables with multiple indices

Tags: python, cplex, cplex-python-api

I'm new to Cplex and I'm working with the python API. I have a variable $w^t_{iksm}$ and I could just find the binary_var_cube function which only accepts 3 indices. I'm then using this $w$ to define $X^z_{ij}$ and $Y_{im}$ which are my decision variables. My question is, how should I code this variable with more than 3 indices?

I'm sorry if this is a basic one, but if you had any useful resources for beginners, please don't hesitate to share them with me.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. It seems that you are asking 'how to define a decision variable with more than 3 indices in Cplex+python API'? I don't get what w_iksm^t and X_ij^z are in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a binary decision variable as:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
m = Model(...)
my_var = m.binary_var("name_of_this_var")
```

The variable is just an object and does not know how many indices it has. You can then maintain your own variable dictionary. So if you have a variable defined for the indices i,k,s,m,t, you could create a dictionary that maps keys defined as tuples to their corresponding variables:

```
var_dict[(i,k,s,m,t)]=m.binary_var("name_of_this_var")
```

To create a large number of variables simultaneously, and to produce a dict or a list, consider using the factory methods `binary_var_dict` or `binary_var_list`. I recommend that you study the examples provided with docplex.